# I'm working on a Google Script within Google Workspace Documents from which I'd like to get not only editor email but also the user name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm working on a Google Script within Google Workspace Documents from which I'd like to get not only editor email but also the user name.

```
function getEditors() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var editors = doc.getEditors();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraph = body.insertParagraph(0, ""); //add paragraph at top of body.
  var editorsTxt = paragraph.appendText("Editores:\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
    editorsTxt = paragraph.appendText(editors[i].toString()+"\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no getUser() method for Document Class.  You could get the current or active user see [Class Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session) But even that will not provide the name of the user.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, `doc.getEditors()` doesn't include the user names while the user emails are included. So, in this case, in order to retrieve the user name, it is required to use a workaround. In this workaround, the user names are retrieved using ContactApp and People API. When those are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this pattern, the user name is retrieved with ContactApp.

```js
function getEditors() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var editors = doc.getEditors();

  var owner = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getOwner();
  var ownerObj = { [owner.getEmail()]: owner.getName() };
  var res = editors.map(e => {
    var email = e.getEmail();
    if (ownerObj[email]) return `${ownerObj[email]} (${email})`;
    var r = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(email);
    return r.length > 0 ? `${r[0].getFullName()} (${email})` : email;
  });
  // console.log(res); // You can confirm the retrieved names using this.

  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraph = body.insertParagraph(0, "");
  paragraph.appendText("Editores:\n");
  res.forEach(e => paragraph.appendText(e + "\n"));
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this pattern, the user name is retrieved with People API. So, [please enable People API at Advances Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function getEditors() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var editors = doc.getEditors();

  var owner = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getOwner();
  var ownerObj = { [owner.getEmail()]: owner.getName() };
  var res = editors.map(e => {
    var email = e.getEmail();
    if (ownerObj[email]) return `${ownerObj[email]} (${email})`;
    var r = People.People.searchContacts({ pageSize: 1, readMask: "emailAddresses,names", query: email });
    return r.results ? `${r.results[0].person.names[0].givenName} ${r.results[0].person.names[0].familyName} (${email})` : email;
  });
  // console.log(res); // You can confirm the retrieved names using this.

  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraph = body.insertParagraph(0, "");
  paragraph.appendText("Editores:\n");
  res.forEach(e => paragraph.appendText(e + "\n"));
}
```

#### Note:

- At the above 2 scripts, `user name (user email)` is returned.
- When the email is not found in your data, the email is used.

#### References:

- [getContactsByEmailAddress(query)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactsbyemailaddressquery)
- [Method: people.searchContacts](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts)